# image alpha channel extraction

Tags: php, image, alpha

Is it possibe to extract the alpha channel of an image and save it as a black and white png using the imagine php library?

I've been looking around but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
private function generateMask($file, $imagine){
    $image = $imagine->open($file->getRealPath());   
    $image = $image->resize(new Imagine\Image\Box(200, 200));
    $mask = $image->mask(); //Creates alpha from grayscale version instead of alpha
    $newImage = $imagine->create(new Imagine\Image\Box(200, 200));
    $newImage->applyMask($mask);
    return $newImage;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried yet?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato I was using mask() but then realised it creates an alpha channel by making a greyscale version of current image instead of extracting the alpha channel. I'll add the code snippet to my original question.